# Excel adding ' in all my cells

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I have a spreadsheet connected externally to my ERP via ODBC, I pull the information into multiple sheets and it was perfectly working until this week.

All the columns that pull numbers are being added with an ' (apostrophe) in front of it, so instead of the number I have now i.e '=1

The field is NOT 'TEXT' and it is not something on my application as I have another user that uses these spreadsheets with the same problem this week.

Nothing has changed on my ERP, I have more than one spreadsheet connected to it and now all of them have the same problem, I believe it was some sort of update in Excel.

Is there anything I have to configure in Excel now? I don't want to sort this with formulas or macro because these spreadsheet are very slow already.

Comment: What OS are you running? What version of Excel/Office? How about your ODBC drivers, what version are they?

Comment: Doesn't sound like an excel problem. Never seen excel randomly add appostrofs to text. Also it doesn't need to do so in order to denote something as text.

Comment: @RichHolton I am running Windows 7, Excel 2016, Driver 32bits.

Comment: @Luuklag I know it sounds weird, but it just started this week, definetly nothing changed on my ERP, I use Netsuite, unless they've changed something on the way they send data now but I don't think so

Comment: This sounds like a driver / configuration issue to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem was indeed the last update in Office, the 'solution' is to roll-back the update, you can follow these steps to do so:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-click-to-run

Answer (score 0):

1. Clearing Formats will solve the issue
2. Copy and Paste Values will also do the same thing
3. Copy/Paste in & out of notepad++ solves this as well

Explanation: Apostrophes in front of text is how Excel determines that it is a text value and not some other kind of data type.

EDIT: Try this to fix and see if this solves the issue. Borrowed from: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=155860

SSIS - Right Click "Excel Destination" --> Advanced Properties --> Input and Output properties --> in tree view select "Excel destination Input" --> External Columns

Comment: Hi Doug,
Unfortunately, this is not ideal, one spreadsheet can have multiple connections (tables), for example, first I pull all my Active Products to one sheet, then I pull all the stock level information to another sheet, then I pull all the invoices to another sheet, then de purchases and so on... Today I've just have to press one button and it refreshes all the sheets with data from my ERP and then I apply macros to join the information in one summary. If I have to copy and paste each sheet I will take hours doing this. 

I am just surprised why this started now with no reason at all.

Comment: @Kirk.Bogwart try my edit as I was researching to see how to prevent it from happening. I was curious and had not ran into this yet

Comment: Where exactly I should try this?

Comment: @Kirk.Bogwart arent you pulling data from SQL Server? If not Ive made a terrible assumption....

Answer (score 0):

Well after a few tests in different computers and versions it seems to be working as expected in Excel 2007, but not in 2016. 
I am afraid that some update during last week caused this so I will have to investigate better what caused it.

@Doug Coats BTW I am not using SQL Server. Thanks